# solution of this differential equation which is a very simple version of ”Cruise Control” logic in a car:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

x''(t) = −k(x'(t) − y(t)),
where x''(t) is acceleration, x'(t) is current speed, y(t) is the desired speed. First,
assume that y(t) is constant; then assume that y(t) is a linear function

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: thank you @Triatticus .. my question is to find the differential equation for this

Comment: You have already written down a differential equation for your problem. It reads $x''(t)=-k(x'(t)-y(t))$. Are you looking for a solution of this equation?

Comment: yes , sorry I am looking for solution of this equation

Answer (score 0):

I give you a hint for the case of $y(t)=c$ being a constant:
Differentiate your equation and you obtain
$$x'''(t)=-k\cdot x''(t). $$
Now set $x''(t)=z(t)$. Then use seperation by variables (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) to solve the resulting differential equation. Then you integrate $z$ twice to obtain $x$.

If $y$ is a linear function, the same idea can be applied. Just differentiate the differential equation twice.

Comment: There isn't any need to do this, this is a second order linear ODE with constant coefficients and is straightforward to solve

Comment: You are right. Variation of constants can be applied as well (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters). On the other hand the above mentioned method just uses seperation of variables and can therefore be applied by beginners without knowing any further theory.